How to force pods on same node when using GKE Autopilot?
I'm trying to run two 1 replica deployments on GKE Autopilot. I would like to have both pods be scheduled on the same node.
I believe I should be able to use PodAffinity to achieve this like so on both deployments:
      affinity:
        podAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: component
                operator: In
                values:
                - app
            topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname

Autopilot spins up one node and schedules one pod but the second pod is just stuck pending, saying no nodes meet affinity rules/resources. I would have expected Autopilot to spin up a larger node to accommodate both pods. Am I missing something here about PodAffinity or how Autopilot works?

There is no mechanism in Kubernetes and GKE that would recreate nodes to better fit the pods. Autoscaling (in GKE and also in OSS Cluster Autoscaler) generally only creates nodes for pending pods and deletes empty/underutilized nodes.
Workload Separation
Use workload separation to force the pods to be scheduled on one (or more if the subsequent pods won't fit) dedicated nodes. Note that it's still possible to have this issue if the sum of the both pods is bigger than the dedicated node size.
workload separation solution:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-app1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: cloud.google.com/compute-class
                operator: In
                values:
                - Scale-Out
      containers:
      - name: hello-app
        image: us-docker.pkg.dev/google-samples/containers/gke/hello-app:1.0
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1Gi"
      tolerations:
        - key: wskey
          operator: Equal
          value: wslabel
          effect: NoSchedule
      nodeSelector:
        wskey: wslabel
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-app2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app2
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - app1
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: cloud.google.com/compute-class
                operator: In
                values:
                - Scale-Out
      containers:
      - name: hello-app
        image: us-docker.pkg.dev/google-samples/containers/gke/hello-app:1.0
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1Gi"
      tolerations:
        - key: wskey
          operator: Equal
          value: wslabel
          effect: NoSchedule
      nodeSelector:
        wskey: wslabel

DaemonSet with Workload Separation
Apply workload separation config on all Deployments and then convert all but one of the Deployments (the leader) to a DaemonSet (DS). Then apply the DS(s) first, followed by the deployment. This will ensure the nodes are big enough to capture all DS(s) and the leader deployment.
You can read more about this in the following link.
